# Beginner in clojure: Tokenizing lists of different characters

Tags: regex, clojure, tokenize

So I know this isn't the best method of solving this issue, but I'm trying to go through a list of lines from an input file, which end up being expressions. I've got a list of expressions, and each expression has it's own list thanks to the split-the-list function. My next step is to replace characters with `id`, ints with `int`, and + or - with `addop`. I've got the regexes to find whether or not my symbols match any of those, but when I try and replace them, I can only get the last for loop I call to leave any lasting results. I know what it stems down to is the way functional programming works, but I can't wrap my head around the trace of this program, and how to replace each separate type of input and keep the results all in one list.

```
(def reint #"\d++")
(def reid #"[a-zA-Z]+")
(def readdop #"\+|\-")

(def lines (into () (into () (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp "input.txt")) )))

(defn split-the-line [line] (clojure.string/split line #" " ))

(defn split-the-list  [] (for [x (into [] lines)] (split-the-line x)))

(defn tokenize-the-line [line] 
(for [x line] (clojure.string/replace x reid "id")) 
(for [x line] (clojure.string/replace x reint "int")) 
(for [x line] (clojure.string/replace x readdop "addop")))

(defn tokenize-the-list [] (for [x (into [] (split-the-list) )] (tokenize-the-line x)))
```

And as you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to functional programming, so any advice is welcome!

Comment: Why are you using all those `into`? The do nothing at all in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `do` block, which evaluates several expressions (normally for side effects) and then returns the last one. You can't see it because `fn` (and hence `defn`) implicitly contain one. As such, the lines

```
(for [x line] (clojure.string/replace x reid "id")) 
(for [x line] (clojure.string/replace x reint "int"))
```

are evaluated (into two different lazy sequences) and then thrown away. 
In order for them to affect the return value, you have to capture their return values and use them in the next round of replacements. 
In this case, I think the most natural way to compose your replacements is the threading macro `->`:

```
(for [x line] 
     (-> x 
         (clojure.string/replace reid "id")
         (clojure.string/replace reint "int")
         (clojure.string/replace readdop "addop")))
```

This creates code which does the `reid` replace with `x` as the first argument, then does the `reint` replace with the result of that as the first argument and so on.

Alternatively you could do this by using `comp` to compose anonymous functions like `(fn [s] (clojure.string/replace s reid "id")` (partial application of `replace`). In the imperative world we get pretty used to running several procedures that "bash the data in place" - in the functional world you more often combine several functions together to do all the operations and then run the result.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes life a lot easier.